# How to Pivot Query Results in MS Access?

Tags: sql, ms-access

After running my query, my results are as follows:

```
user  report   rights
1       a       FULL
1       b       FULL
1       c       FULL
1       d       READ
2       b       FULL
2       c       FULL
3       a       FULL
3       b       READ
3       c       READ
```

I would like to pivot these results in this format:

```
user    a       b       c       d
1       FULL    FULL    FULL    FULL
2               READ    FULL        
3       FULL    READ    READ
```

Basically, I would like each user listed once and display the report names as columns. Then show the rights of the user for each report. I am using MS Access for this query. Please suggest a way to display my query results as shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the crosstab query, a unique command in Jet/ACE SQL:

```
TRANSFORM Max(t.rights) AS MaxOfrights
SELECT t.user
FROM accTable t
GROUP BY t.user
PIVOT t.report;
```

Comment: There is even a wizard for creating this.